# GLSL get relative normalized coordinates of the fragment

Tags: opengl, glsl

in a fragment shader, without a texture associated to it, how do I get normalized coordinates that start, for instance, on `(0, 0)` on the top left corner of my geometry, and `(1, 1)` on the bottom-right corner? This should be independent of the geometry I'm using

Comment: How do you define "your geometry"? Since "geometry" tends to be 3D, how do you define "top left" and "bottom right"?

Comment: Do you know your "geometry" bounding box before sending it to GPU?

Comment: @NicolBolas I create a simple 2D quad

Comment: What's the problem in adding a vertex attribute that's (0,0) in one corner and (1,1) in another?

Comment: @ybungalobill is it the best option?

Comment: did you figure it out?